# Are there any existing projects that run the dart test runner on travis-ci with chrome_shell --dump-render-tree?

Tags: dart, travis-ci

I'm looking for an example of a project that runs dart unit tests on travis-ci using chrome shell.  I'm working doing this myself, and figure to save a lot of time if there is an example of this already happening elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Dart support in Travis](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/pull/357) should land soon. It will start without support of browser tests.

Once the PR is merged I will add the browser support with *content_shell*. You can grab some informations on how to set up *content_shell* in the last comments of the PR.